# Using BSL to program MSP430 MCU with JTAG fused already blown and all memory wiped out by BSL

Tags: microcontroller, flash, jtag, erase

If the Texas Instrument MSP430 MCU (specifically Fxxx series) has the JTAG fuse already blown and the BSL was able to erase the whole chip (either by using force erase all or wrongly inputted password).

Can you access the blank flash memory via BSL (which I presumed has the base code written in ROM)  and reprogram (or reuse) the chip just by accessing via BSL?  If it is possible, how is BSL debugging and testing compared to direct JTAG programming.

Is the former very hard?

Comment: Which family? (There are different Fxxx families.)

Comment: m430f2617 family

Answer (score 2):

JTAG and BSL are separate interfaces. JTAG has all kinds of debugging functions, but the only purpose of the BSL is to write the firmware into the flash.

When you use the BSL to write your firmware, then the only debugging and testing functions are those that you have implemented in your firmware.

Comment: So if the JTAG fuse was blown. And you can only access the whole memory via BSL after erase all function was done. You can still make the MCU run any normal function (except debugging) via BSL programming, right?

Comment: Your new firmware will run normally.

Comment: For the F2617. If incorrect password is entered into an existing firmware and the BSL delete all memory from the incorrect password. why can one still access the blank memory via BSL? why did Texas Instruments not make BSL inaccessible after it got incorrect password? this way, no one can access the MCU to write new firmware for the whole gadget.

Comment: The purpose of the BSL password is to prevent reading the firmware.

Comment: i know and if you enter wrong password, it can delete all the main memory. But even with JTAG fuse blown prior to it. one can still access the MCU after all memory deleted by making new firmware via the BSL. Is this correct? or if wrong password enter and all memory wiped out. maybe you cant access the main memory anymore via BSL? im not sure of the answer that is why im asking for clarification what is the case. Tnx

Comment: I'll give an illustration. Supposed a nuclear missile is controlled by an M430 MCU inside. It has the JTAG fuse blown and the BSL has password. If a terrorist tried to access the BSL with wrong password, it erased the main memory. But then he can still create new firmware to it and launch. Why doesn't Texas Instruments make the BSL inoperative after wrong password enter so no new firmware can be entered to lunch the nukes?

Comment: The terrorist could solder a new MSP430 chip onto the board. This is not what the BSL tries to protect against.

Comment: for the other series i read "Completely disable the BSL using signature or erasing the BSL". Does it mean the BSL can be disabled if wrong password entered for those series?

Comment: On those chips, the BSL can be disabled either by a special signature in the flash, or by erasing the flash that contains the BSL.

Comment: Maybe. You'd have to try.